# Google fetch and render shows redirect error

Tags: redirect, nginx, fetch, google-search-console

In my Google search console I try to `fetch and render` my pages but I get redirect error because of `http` to `https` redirect. Is it possible to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If like me you had the URL in the Wordpress General setting as http:// (without the www) you need to add the "www". This is a link to page info on this.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96568#2